# $f'(0)$ when $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f'(0)$ when $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, $f(0)=0$

This is presented as an MCQ and answer is given as "$f$ is differentiable at every $ x$ but $f'$ is discontinous at $0$ "

I calculated LHD and RHD at $0$ as $0$ and $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ which is not defined at 0 thus the answer should be "$f$ is not differentiable at $0$"

Is this a misprint or am I missing something?

Comment: $f$ **is** differentiable at $0$: $\lim_{h\to 0}(f(h)-f(0))/(h-0)$ **does** exist.

Comment: This question I am sure, has been asked before...

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. The right-hand derivative is _not_ (necessarily) $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$. The right-hand derivative is $\lim_{h\to 0^+}(f(0+h)-f(0))/h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is defined at $0$, since$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}x=\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)=0.$$What isn't defined at $0$ is $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$, but that's another matter.

Comment: $f'(0)$ not defined. Is that why $f'$ is discontinous at 0?

Comment: @AFalseName Please read Jose's answer and my comment. $f'(0)$ **is** defined.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, $f'$ **is** defined at $0$; it is equal to $0$ there. But since $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ doesn't exist, $f'$ isn't continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use that $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ and let $$x_0=0$$ then we have
$$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\frac{h^2\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=h\sin(\frac{1}{h})$$
so $$\lim_{h\to 0}h\sin(\frac{1}{h})=0$$